# How can I do this in excel

Tags: excel, formula

I am new to excel formulas. I know the basics but this is one is a challenge for me. Please consider the below screenshot:

[image]

Now assume that today's date is ***16-4-2018***. What I want is to Count the number of Post ID's which are having the Status (***Column D***) as "***Analyzing***" but also the Validity date (***Column F***) should be in future i.e. it should be greater than today's date (***16-4-2018***). The count should then be displayed in front of "***Posts in Analysis***" row 5.

I tried using the CountIF function but cannot get it to work. I don't know what condition to put in. Currently, it's showing the count as 3 but it should show 2.

Any ideas how to write the formula?

P.S. Don't take the Time (Column E) into consideration.

Comment: Could you show the formula(s) you've used so far in case there is a type?

Comment: You need `COUNTIFS`.

Comment: =COUNTIF(Sheet1!D7:D1000000,"Analyzing"). I am completely a newbie to formulas. I have no idea how to use CountIFs.

Comment: Just click on the formula button and search for COUNTIFS, there is a pretty good documentation and examples in the Excel help. It should be fairly simple if your date column is actually formatted as a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B36,"Analyzing",F2:F36,">"&TODAY())
```

Just modify the ranges, the rest will be the same. The formula should be placed next to "Posts in Analysis" as you wished.

Comment: Thanks a lot Srpic :) This is just what I wanted :)